# Git revert hard : files from another branch remain in the project

Tags: git

I needed to revert the project to an old commit after which another "branch B" have been merged into the current "branch A".
After executing **git reset --hard** files from that other "branch B" still remain in the project in the "branch A"
How to really return to the version in "branch A" as it was before ?

Here is the graph explaining the situation

[image]

Comment: Could you try to post a graph of the commit history? I'm having a really hard time understanding what you are saying.

Comment: How about you don't use A and B and use the actual branch names? According to your history, you were either on branch develop or SyncfGanttComponent. Reading your commits further, I would assume your blue selected commit was on branch develop. So, you checked out a specific commit on develop, you saw extra files from ... which branch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the target commit ID, is the commit where you want to return, once you have the commit ID `git checkout -b <commit-ID>` this will result in a new branch in the point do you want. then you can do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git clean` to remove all files that are untracked an not in `.gitignore` from disk :

```
# first run it with `-n` to see the list of files that would be deleted :
git clean -n -d

# if the list contains only files which you want to delete, replace `-n` with `-f` :
git clean -f -d
```

*warning* : `git clean -f` is one of the few destructive commands, which can delete from disk some files that are not tracked in your repo.

If `git clean` would remove too many files (e.g : you have some `file.list` or some `script.sh` which is not part of the repo but you want to keep on disk ...), you can view the list of files "present in B but not in current commit" :

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D B HEAD

# if your previous commit was not the tip of branch B, you can replace 'B' with that
# commit's hash in  the above command
```

If you confirm that this list of files is to be deleted :

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D B HEAD | xargs rm
```

---

If you ran `git reset --hard` in one go to the target commit, it is indeed weird to still have these files on disk.

However, it could be explained if you ran it with some extra commands in between

e.g : I regularly run `git reset <somecommit>`, before realizing I wanted `git reset --hard <somecommit>`. Except that the first `git reset ...` command has left the files from the initial branch in the worktree, *untracked*, so the second `git reset --hard ...` will not remove them.